# MVC protecting accessing some action

Tags: action, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question regarding some action accessing, i'm not talking here about authorization etc, but more about the direct access to actions.

Basically i have 2 question, 1 general and 1 more contextual:

Situation imaging i have an action : MyArticles/DeleteArticle/id

1) How can i prevent that if someone will just put this url with a proper id remove article? How can i say that it can only be used with a button on my website? And should this action be a get or post?
At this moment i use  $.ajax and GET method ....

2) Now imagine i have many people, and if all th ppl are registered, they can delete each others article, what if i want to avoid that and let users only delete their own articles, because at this moment for example if they can guess the id they can directly access the action with id and delete it.

Can anyone provide explanation and some tips about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm not talking here about authorization etc

Yes, you are.  The authorization to delete the article should take place within the action itself, it's not the responsibility of the calling code or of any UI which displays a link to the action.

> How can i say that it can only be used with a button on my website?

I imagine any approach to that is going to complicate the issue tremendously.  Understand how HTTP requests work... Your application isn't making the request to the action, *the user* is.  They're doing so (in the general case) by clicking a link on an interface provided by your application, but the request itself is coming from the user.  (Well, from the user's web browser, which is in their control and not yours.)

The most straightforward approach to this is to encapsulate authorization in the action itself (or, better still, in the model functionality being invoked by the action... but logically that's still part of the "request" being performed).

When you expose a piece of functionality which not everybody should be able to invoke, put the authorization on the functionality itself instead of on the UI which invokes it.  That way no matter *how* it's invoked it always maintains the authorization, instead of just assuming that some other component maintained it.

Comment: But regarding the autorization it has different roles like admin, member etc ... so imaging everyone has access to his own page and has right there to add or delete an article ... so if any member goes to his page and types this code to delete article with correct id, it can delete the article of other member

Comment: @Alnedru: Roles are only part of authorization.  Roles determine, horizontally across the domain, which users are permitted to make which requests.  They don't filter, vertically, the entities on which each user may make each request.  That's less generic, more customized business logic.  Your code would check that the user making the request is allowed to delete that instance.  (Perhaps passing a user identifier to a `Delete` method on the model and internally checking that the identifier matches the owner/creator of that instance, for example.)

Comment: Ok, I understand basically i myself should verify who is responsible for which item etc etc ...

Comment: @Alnedru: Correct.  A lot of this is "commonly built" functionality, but it's still "custom" enough that there isn't much in the way of out-of-the-box tooling for it.  Who is allowed to edit what data is very subjective (admins, parent/owning accounts, users who created the content, etc.) and really falls under business logic, not infrastructure logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of control in MVC with respect to the USER. To allow a user to delete only his own work, you must remember in the database who wrote what. If this is the case - and you know it, a simple if statement in the beginning of the action will do the trick.